HTML: Dropdown of a select field should have the same width
I need a method to give the options (the dropdown) of a native select element the same width as the select field.
So if I give a select field the width 8rem using css (select { width: 8rem}) then I want all elements in my dropdown to be 8rem wide as well. If the text of an option is longer, it should wrap.
Is this somehow possible with a native select? I am not allowed to use/build a custom select field for accessibility reasons. I know select fields are hard to style but maybe there is a good workaround im not aware of.
I can use javascript, css and html.

No. It's not possible, well... unless you calculate the font size (for all options) necessary to match the select's width... But I would not go that way. Why — would you ever want to do that? What should happen to the option value if its content suddenly overflows the 8em?

I doubt there would be a reliable way to do this, especially across browsers/platforms.  You'd instead probably want to focus on the "accessibility reasons" that disallow creating the UI you want to create, as accessible custom drop-down menus are not at all uncommon.

And PS, by default options will have approximately a "min-width" matching the select's one (if width is set).
